# CSV Import to Mysql data not being added to table

Tags: mysql, csv, import

Hi I have the following piece of code which is supposed to upload a csv file and add the information to the database.  even though it gets to the echo import complete no data is being added to the table.

```
copy($_FILES["fileCSV"]["tmp_name"],"shotdev/".$_FILES["fileCSV"]["name"]); // Copy/Upload CSV

$objCSV = fopen("shotdev/".$_FILES["fileCSV"]["name"], "r");
while (($objArr = fgetcsv($objCSV, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $strSQL = "INSERT INTO customer_list ";
    $strSQL .="(company_name,website,owner,email_addredd,client_id) ";
    $strSQL .="VALUES ";
    $strSQL .="('".$objArr[0]."','".$objArr[1]."','".$objArr[2]."' ";
    $strSQL .=",'".$objArr[3]."','".$objArr[4]."','".$objArr[5]."') ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
}
fclose($objCSV);

echo "Import completed.";
```

This is my table structure

```
     customer_list` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `company_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `website` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `owner` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `email_addredd` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `client_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what is wrong, but you should be testing the value of  `$objQuery`. If it is false, you should echo `mysql_error()` and die. That is the standard way to call `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I echoed $objquery but it returned nothing so does that mena there is a problem with the query do you think?

Comment: That is not what I asked you to do.